# Blender Export to gITF format loses Rotation transform setting XYZ Euler switches to Quaternion instead

Tags: export, blender, quaternions, euler-path

On exporting from Blender to gITF 2.0 format the rotation Transform setting goes to Quaternion WXYZ instead of staying XYX Euler.

Let me know if there is way around.

Expecting on Export from Blender to giTF format to retain rotation Transform setting to stay XYZ Euler.

No Frames exist.